# Git - Find authors who changed a file

Tags: git, logging

Is there a way in git to list out authors who changed a specific file?

For now all I could do was `git log [filename] | grep "Author"`

Comment: `git log --pretty=%an -- <file_name>`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is the following command

`git shortlog -sn [filename]`

Comment: Is this the answer? If this outputs the list of authors who changed a specific file, say so and accept your answer.

Comment: SO has restricted accepting your own answers until the next 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific need, you could use `git blame` to see who added lines on the file. Deleted lines are more trycky because `git blame --reverse` does not tell you where the lines were actually deleted.... I've been working on a tool that mixes the output of git diff with git blame (with a litlle bit of analysis of deleted lines) that might come handy. https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame